# Replace string with mysql

Tags: mysql, replace

I have a site with a domain "mydomainA.com". I moved to a site "mydomainB.com".
The problem: I have a lot of images in the pages that link to "mydomainA.com". I would like to save time and find a MySQL query that replaces all occurrences of a term ... by another to replace all occurrences of "mydomainA" by "mydomainB".

But is that really possible?

Otherwise, I would use php preg_replace edn.

Sincerely,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax of replace is

```
UPDATE table1 SET field1 = REPLACE(field1,'value1','value2')
WHERE field1 LIKE '%value1%'
```

Check replace function [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_replace).

Here is an [example](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-select-replace/)

Comment: Thank you. With your example link, I can see the power of replace function.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE links SET url = REPLACE( url, 'mydomainA.com', 'mydomainB.com' )
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are looking for the [Replace](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) MySQL command. Combined with an UPDATE just does its job.